# What kind of shader should I use to render hair

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d, xna, shader

I have a 3D model looks like this in 3Dmax:

[image]

I develop a program(C# XNA/OpenGL) to read 3D models and apply material, so it looks like this:

[image]

However the model is created by facegen and hair looks like this in facegen:

[image]

So my questions is what kind shader should I use to render the hair so it can look like the one in Facegen.

Comments, keywords,hits,samples, tutorials or code anything are welcome.

My platform

Windows 7 64bits
C# OR C++ 
XNA OR Directx OR OPENGL

Comment: One starting point: [GPU Gems 2, Chapter 23](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems2/gpugems2_chapter23.html).

Comment: I'm asking my barber for a tessellated-Bezier cut next time.

Comment: Thanks, Jerry I will check it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an nVidia hair demo called Nalu that you can find in the nVidia samples here: https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-graphics-sdk-11-direct3d. The shader used is called Marschner shader and you can google more info about it. Ofcourse there are many other techniques for hair rendering and many other shaders.

Also there's a blog specifically with hair rendering resources http://hairrendering.wordpress.com/ with good information.

Answer (score 1):

One pretty good technique is to use particles for hair, but instead of rendering points you instead render lines.

One way to do this is to render the entire particles lifetime all in one go, as opposed to rendering a specific point at a specific time. Used alongside something like bezier curves you can get some really realistic looking hair. You can even go further and simulate wind blowing the hair etc, simply by manipulating the path of the particles using a vertex field or something similar

Comment: Thanks for your hints, Moore91

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, facegen looks like it's just laying down the hair polygons with alpha blending based on the texture, and UNLIT so that sorting issues for transparent are hard to spot. The choice of hair method depends on many considerations, including the kind of renderer (forward/deferred), the required performance, whether you're willing to sort the hair polygons (or chunks)...

The Marschner method is excellent but complex. Try alphablending as I've described if you just want quick and simple.

Comment: Yes, the Marathoner filter give me a 14FPS on my Macbook Pro. I will check the alphablending, thanks.